# Successively change variables from JSON objects with while loop (Python)

Tags: python, json, while-loop, get

Most of the questions about getting variables from JSON objects are in Javascript; I am working in Python. I am trying to generate a list of articles from an API, spanning a range of some years, and retrieving every article with a given keyword. The tricky part is that the API only allows ten list items per query; so I need to revise the query after each iteration. My query is structured as so:

```
# Search for articles published between a begin and end date
begin_date = 19800101
end_date = 19891231
query_url = f"{url}api-key={api_key}&q={query}&begin_date={begin_date}&end_date={end_date}"
```

My original code returned a list of ten articles, in descending order, as follows:

```
1989-12-26 Article Title
1989-12-16 Article Title
1989-11-16 Article Title
1989-10-13 Article Title
1989-10-11 Article Title
1989-10-10 Article Title
1989-09-25 Article Title
1989-09-23 Article Title
1989-10-03 Article Title
1989-09-01 Article Title
```

So, what I am trying to do is take the date of the last list item, and make that the new end_date to run the query again. I attempted to do this with a while loop:

```
while end_date > begin_date:
    # Build url
    articles = requests.get(query_url).json()
    for doc in (articles['response']['docs']):
        data = {
            "date": doc['pub_date'].split('T')[0],
            "headline": doc['headline']['print_headline'],
            "abstract": doc['abstract']
        }
        article_list.append(data)
        end_date = int(data["date"].replace("-", ""))
    print(end_date)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Unfortunately, it got stuck in an endless loop, printing 19890901 eighteen times, until I did a keyboard interrupt. I then ran the rest of the code starting after the while loop, and it was merely the same list of ten articles as before. Where did I go wrong?